# com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device offline (Even when device is connected)

Tags: android, android-studio, build

After update of Android Studio to 2.1.2 I've been getting the following error too many times when i make a change.

> com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device offline
>
> Error while Installing APK

**The problem is device was never connected and is not offline**

If i unplug and re-plug the device it starts working fine again. This never happened in the previous version of AS.

Question: Is there a setting to be changed in AS for this to stop happening or it is a bug?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 24):

Invalidate your Studio cache, restart your device and pc will work. Sometimes the problem with port also, just try after changing the usb port of your pc also.

Comment: It's windows driver / hardware problem.

Comment: in my case restarting the device worked, Mi A2 running android pie

Answer (score 8):

Re-enabling *USB Debugging* fixed the problem

**Settings** > **Developer Options** > Disable & *Re*-enable **USB Debugging**

Answer (score 7):

You just need to restart **ADB** , no need to restart your **PC** or **Phone**

Try the below steps:

Go to the **Android SDK** platform-tools directory in the command prompt

Type `adb kill-server`
Then type `adb start-server`

Now try re-connecting ...

[image: It Worked!]

In my case I was **debugging over wifi** for a long time , then the **ADB server needed to be refreshed** to see the connected devices again

> It Happened on **Pixel device** running **Android 8.1.0** with **Android Studio 3.0**

Cheers!

Comment: I agreed, I just restarted adb.exe from windows task manager and started debugging on android studio. changing the USB port also may help

Answer (score 2):

**Try Disabling and Re-Enabling * USB debugging. ***

Under your developer option menu

**This solved my issue.**

Answer (score 1):

I have "revoked USB debugging authorizations " under "Developer options" and it works

Answer (score 1):

I changed settings in the Developer options in my phone and it started working just fine.

1.Permission to install apps from unknown source
2.permission to install apps via USB.

Answer (score 1):

Had Same Problem, Just rebooted and its fixed, its the connection problem actually, so check phone's cable first

Answer (score 1):

I got it solved 
for mac
 Android>Preferences>Build,Execution, Deployment>Debugger ---Uncheck => Use libusb backend

for windows
File>Settings>Build,Execution, Deployment>Debugger ---Uncheck => Use libusb backend

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have activated Unknown sources in my cellphone to let application installation. Because the app hasn't accepted by Google yet, so it will block installation process.

To activate Unknown sources (In my device Samsung Galaxy Tab A 9.7 is):

```
Lock screen and security
```

Answer (score 0):

unplug your device and click on run and after visiting selection window, plug your device again and select your connected device. it will work!

Answer (score 0):

I have changed it from **Charge The Device** to **File Transfer** and it works every time.

Answer (score 0):

Had the Same Problem .. Solved after restart My AS and My Device, Don't forget to check your Caple.

Answer (score 0):

Change USB port and use another USB port of your PC or Laptop. This works for me!

Answer (score 0):

1. restart and in validate android studio
2. Disable and enable usb debugging
3. unplug device
4. plug device
5. uninstall existing app
6. kill and start adb server
7. YourComputer@YourComputer:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ adb kill-server
8. YourComputer@YourComputer:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ adb start-server

- daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
- daemon started successfully

8. Run app again
9. if it doesn't work ensure u cable or connection is good

Answer (score -2):

**Tools**>>**AVD Manager** >>**Actions** >>Select you Device **More** >> **Wipe Data**

Start again Device