# Android studio giving error "com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device offline" even though device is connected

Tags: android

Android studio giving error 
"com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device offline
Error while Installing APK" even though android device is connected.

I tried by adb kill-server and adb start-server but after this kill  and start process first time code runs properly but second time again gives the same error.

Please If anyone knows the solution share , Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37856539/com-android-ddmlib-adbcommandrejectedexception-device-offline-even-when-device

Comment: show the `adb devices` command line output

Comment: This is adb command line output  :                                                                                                                                                                                     C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb kill-server

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>